# How to mount all partitions listed on the fstab with Ansible

Tags: ansible

After using Ansible's `lineinfile` module to add multiple mount points to `/etc/fstab`, I'd like to run a simple `mount -a` to bring those into effect.

It DOES work with

```
  - name: mount all
    command: mount -a
    become: true
```

however ansible insists on suggesting to use the `mount` module

```
[WARNING]: Consider using mount module rather than running mount
```

But as far as I can see, there is no easy option to do that.

Am I missing something?

**Update 2023**

Adding items via `mount` and `state: present` as suggested by Mohqas would be a better approach than using `lineinfile`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right, the `mount` module in the current version of Ansible works on a per-mount basis and does not allow mounting all filesystems defined in `/etc/fstab`. The way you implemented the task is correct.

What you see in the output is a warning:

> [WARNING]: Consider using [mount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html) module rather than running mount

Ansible checks you are running `mount` command through `command` module and suggests using the native module.

Ansible does not perform advanced syntax analysis to verify if the particular set of arguments, which you used in the command call, is possible to be implemented using native module parameters or not.

You can disable warnings for `shell` and `command` modules on a per-task basis by setting the `warn` argument to `no`:

```
- name: mount all
  command: mount -a
  args:
    warn: no
  become: true
```

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, you can add FS tab entries using the mount module, and the state "present". This way, no mounting occurs, and you can mount all entries at once using mount all.

```
- name: Mount drive
  mount:
    name: new mount
    src: /dev/xvdb1
    fstype: ext4
    state: present
```

I basically use this approach due to ansible using the flag "remount" when attempting to mount partitions. This flag does not play nicely with glusterfs for example, as it would throw an error of "drive is already mounted", which would break your ansible run.

Answer (score -4):

Backup of current fstab:

```
#cp -a /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bk
```

process the output of **lsblk -f** using **sed** and **awk** and redirect output to fstab:

```
#lsblk -f|sed 's/\[SWAP]/swap /g'|awk '/(-)/{printf"UUID=%-36s %-23s %-7s defaults 
           0 0\n", $3, ($4==""?mnt"NR:$4), $2}'>/etc/fstab
```

mount the new mount points by invoking

```
#mount -a
```